# What is does mean of webkit? What it makes chrome webkit browsers?

Tags: google-chrome, safari, webkit, mobile-webkit

Can any one help me to understand about webkit.

What is mean by webkit?

What does it make chrome or safari a webkit browser?

What is the difference with mozilla ?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: It cant be more simpler than this http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/WebKit   :P

Answer (score 2):

Paul Irish recently wrote a good article about this: http://paulirish.com/2013/webkit-for-developers/

Hope it helps.

Comment: Nice article! More exhaustive than my quick post could ever be.

Comment: It's not what you know, it's what you Google and bookmark, and that's a very good article.

Answer (score 1):

[Webkit](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/WebKit) is the **rendering engine** that those browsers utilise. In contrast, Firefox's is called Gecko, IE's is called Trident.

Every rendering engine project is a complete separate effort to achieve the same goal: taking  the HTML and CSS you receive, interpreting it and <strike>painting it</strike> calling the particular OS's APIs, asking them to paint it onto the screen.

An example for importance in the daily web development work are the CSS prefixes (i.e. `-webkit-border-radius` vs. `-moz-border-radius`). So if something works on Safari, it's more likely to work straightaway on Chrome more than it is on Firefox - but that's just a family resemblance, at the end of the day you'll still have to test each as every webkit browser product and version still uses a different version of WebKit.

Comment: IE's engine has always been and still is known as Trident, although the assembly file is called mshtml.dll.

Comment: Thx for claryfing, should have pointed out that it was just my assumption. Updated my post to reflect that.

Answer (score 1):

Webkit is a browser engine- used by Safari, Chrome and most probably Opera will began using it as well. It helps rendering the webpages on user end.

Comment: I like short answers:)